# Need help removing favorites from SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

Im recreating the Google Translate app for a school project. When you translate a text the user can save userInput and translation so that they can go back to se it. The problem with my code starts when the user wants to remove the previous saved translation. When the user presses StarButton the isStarred value changes and I want to delete this previously saved translation and userInput. The problem is that I need to get the index of where the user pressed StarButton and then send it to removeFromSharedPreferences(). I have tried multiple options and I will be grateful for every help.

Comment: Can you share more of your code so you know what are you exactly using?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code provided i will assume that `StarButton` is a custom widget that you created. You could simply put an **attribute** index to its class and then pass it in the **constructor**. In this way, every time you initialize a StarButton, you're gonna pass and `index` that identifies its position.

```dart
class StarButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  const StarButton ({ super.key, required this.index});

  @override
  State<StarButton> createState() => _StarButtonState();
}

class _StarButtonState extends State<StarButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return YourWidget();
  }
}
```